# Create Access Control List on Windows 7 with C#

Tags: c#, winapi

How do you set an Access Control List for a new desktop you create with C#? The desktop will be created with `CreateDesktop()` for a different user than the user that runs the program, and a SECURITY_ATTRIBUTE needs to be set that disallows anyone but owner to create a process on the new desktop.

I need to set that specific ACL using SDDL where this new user is set as owner using its SID, and **only** allowing the owner to create processes for the new desktop.

Comment: subject is interesting so +1 from me, but you'd better edit your question and explain a bit better what exactly you want to do. Give rights to a user on a remote machine from a remote machine running your application or what else/more?

Comment: I want to create a new desktop as a local user, and that desktop should allow the creation of a new user aswell.